# About the convergence of the series $\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{m_kp_k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

As usual, let it be $p_k$ the $k$-th prime.

For each $p_k$ one can define
$$m_k=\min\,\{m\in N:\,mp_k+1\;\;is\;prime\}$$
and **consider the following series**
$$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{m_kp_k+1}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
The series (1) seems to converge but I am not sure this is true. Up to the $10^7$-th prime, the summation gives the value $1.0278802480162903...$

**Could it be found a formal way to decide the convergence of such series?**

Many thanks.

Comment: You're sure this *is* decidable, formally?

Comment: Maybe one could be able to show that the series is dominated by the convergent $\,\sum_k \frac 1 {k^2}$.

Comment: I see no reason why $m$ cannot be quite small for many primes, in fact I can well imagine this series to be divergent. Consider that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges very slow (and the reciprocals of the primes of the form $an+b$ with coprime $a,b$ still diverges!) , maybe this series diverges even slower. I see little hope for a decision.

Comment: Or maybe not. $m_k$ can't be $2$ for all primes $p_k$, but for all I know, it could be smaller than $10^{10^{10^{5}}}$ for all $k$, and then, the sum would be divergent.

Comment: $m_k=2\,$ only if $\,p_k\,$ is a Sophie-Germain prime. I don't know which their density is.

Comment: In fact, we do not even know whether infinite many Sophie-Germain primes exist !

Comment: The comment about the possibility that $m$ is bounded is very good (I could not upvote it because of the daily limit)

Comment: To have at least a little evidence , repeat the calculation for larger ranges of the primes and look whether the sum seems to converge. Of course, this way we cannot decide whether the sum diverges or not.

Comment: For example there is at least one prime $np+1$  with $p$ prime and $n<p$.

Comment: @ToniMhax Sure that this is a proven result ?

Comment: That is a question sorry i have no idea

Comment: @Peter According to wp, the best known bound for the exponent in [Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem) is still $5$. I suspect deciding convergence or divergence of $(1)$ is still out of reach.

Comment: Note that $\sum p^{-1} = \infty$ but $\sum_{p \text{ known to us}} p^{-1} <4$. Since its order is $\log\log$, we cannot guess the convergence of that kind of series by such an observation like $\sum a_p < 1.02...$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random model for the primes predicts that the $m_k$ are approximatively independent random variables with $$Pr[m_k <\log^2\log p_k]\approx \sum_{d=0}^{\log^2 \log p_k}(1- \frac1{\log p_k})^d \frac1{\log p_k}$$ $$\approx 1-(1- \frac1{\log p_k})^{\log^2 \log p_k}\approx \frac{\log^2 \log p_k}{\log p_k}$$
so that $$\Bbb{E}[\sum_k \frac1{m_kp_k+1}]\le \sum_k (\frac{C\log^2 \log p_k}{\log p_k}\frac1{p_k+1}+\frac1{p_k \log^2 \log p_k+1})<\infty$$ which means that $$Pr[\sum_k \frac1{m_kp_k+1}=\infty]=0$$

It is probably out of reach to prove it does really converge. If someone can prove it diverges  they will earn the Fields medal.